# Don't modern (2018) browsers support forEach?

Tags: javascript, loops

today I had a test in web technologies. One of the questions was

> Which loops exist in JavaScript?

The possible answers were:

> 1. while, do-while, for, foreach
> 2. while, do-while, for
> 3. while,do-while, for-next
> 4. while, do-while, for, foreach, repeat-until
> 5. while, for, foreach, for-next

I have chosen the answer 1.

And it appeared to be wrong. The comment I have received to my answer is:

> WHILE, DO-WHILE and FOR are the most used standardised loops in
>   javascript. Modern browsers implement ECMAScript4, and
>   these do not support any other loops. Note: ECMAScript5 supports newly
>   FOREACH, but this is still not implemented in the modern browsers.
>
> The correct answer is: while, do-while, for

My question is: isn't this comment kind of outdated? Or is the [w3schools's statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp) about the full support of ECMAScript5 wrong?

Comment: As in `Array.prototype.forEach`? It's very debatable whether that counts as a "loop" or not. Then `.map` and such should probably count as a loop as well.

Comment: They forgot about `for...in` and `for...of`. Whoever prepared the test does not have enough knowledge. And `foreach` is definitely not a language construct, loops are.

Comment: Define "modern" browser…

Comment: That answer is completely outdated (by at least seven years): [`Array.prototype.forEach` browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: That's one heck of an outdated answer. "Modern browsers implement ECMAScript4" made me facepalm since modern browsers implement ES6/ES7+ these days. Even more so since ECMAScript 4 (ES4) was never released in the first place

Comment: `foreach` is NOT `Array.prototype.forEach`. It's a specific type of loop and judging by the context it actually asks about the specific *keyword* itself. For reference, `foreach` exists as a loop statement in PHP amongst other languages but not in JavaScript. However, the foreach *functionality* does exist in JS - it's actually the `for...of` loop introduced in ES6, and `for...in` is also similar in concept but not exactly the same. Anyway, `.forEach` is not considered a loop - it's an array method that applies a function against each member. The actual implementation can be anything.

Comment: @deceze: I understand "modern" as "used by the majority in 2018", but maybe my understanding is wrong

Comment: @vlaz, how do you understand the comment about the support of `FOREACH` in ECMAScript5?

Comment: There are 4 while, do-while, for, for in, I wouldn't call this `Array.prototype.forEach` or this `Array.prototype.map` etc, since those are a built-in methods not loops for but methods that implement those loops, however since they didn't include the, for in, the second answer is the correct one.

Comment: I am not insisting that forEach is a loop. I think that @vlaz and @deceze are making a good point. But would you say that `while, do-while, for` is the correct answer?

Comment: @evnica to be frank, I don't really understand it. My best guess is that at the time the question was written, a `foreach` was *proposed* for ES5 but hasn't been approved yet. The question itself is very nonsensical and outdated, considering `Modern browsers implement ECMAScript4` is blatantly wrong - ES4 was never released (also noted in the link you have in your question). Browsers may have supported some of the proposed ES4 features (that later turned into ES5) but they cannot be compatible with a non-existent standard.

Comment: As for the correct answer, *of the listed ones* number 2 is correct. Still, it is missing `for...in` and `for...of`. Even if we are to assume it's outdated, it should have mentioned `for...in`. Still, it's not completely incorrect in their omission, as it technically asks "Which exist" not "what is an exhaustive list of all loops in JS". So, if we take it as the former, `foreach` doesn't exist as a keyword (although `for...in` is close in concept, assuming no `for...of`), `for-next` also doesn't exist, neither does `repeat-until`. Not as keywords, at least.

Comment: @vlaz, and everyone who helped me to make the issue clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:

Below is a longer answer as to why I think the question is biased, and your answer is correct. However that long explanation isn't even needed. Your professor's quote is not only outdated but the actual statement from w3schools provides exactly what we're looking for:

> ECMAScript 5 is fully supported in all modern browsers*.

When you look to see what the `*` in the quote is for, you'll see it's because IE9 doesn't support ECMAScript 5, but this is fine because as you can find in my answer below, IE9 does indeed support foreach :)

---

#### Original answer:

Not only is the list of possible answers incomplete, the question is biased and ill-defined. Without previously defining the term "modern" and without including it in the question, you can't possibly answer the question without bias.

The only way the question could be valid is if "modern" was defined and a specific version number was specific for each applicable browser.

Even if this was done, which would technically make it so the question could be answered without bias, it would require keeping the definition up to date - well because, IE 5 was a "modern browser" at one point and it obviously isn't anymore. When does a "modern browser" stop being a "modern browser"? That's obviously a question doomed to be riddled with bias.

I slightly disagree with the other (very valid) answer which noted `foreach` may have been referring to the similar `for each` VBScript or `foreach` PHP statement. Because other answer choices contained strings like `repeat-until` and `for-next`, I think the point was to choose the correct keywords/strings, not the correct "statements".

Finally, according to the Mozilla Developer Network documentation (which is a terrific source to find anything dealing with modern web development), `foreach` is supported by every modern browser back to IE9:

```
Feature   Chrome  Edge   Firefox   Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
foreach   Yes     Yes    1.5       9                   Yes     Yes
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: thank you. In my particular case your answer is the most helpful, since the only reason for the professor to consider my choice with `foreach` as invalid was the absence of support in modern browsers. I am also thankful to you and everybody who helped me realize that forEach() is a method and not a loop in terms of a language construct.

Comment: Why would someone stuff the `foreach` _function_ inside a list that only contains names of looping statements from various programming languages? The explanation given to OP is lame and wrong.

Comment: Salman: If you would like your comments to be taken seriously, then you should probably take the time to come up with actual reasoning rather than claiming something is "lame and wrong" -_-  Regardless, your argument of the other strings in the list being looping statements is moot. You're arguing that students in modern web dev classes should recognize "repeat until" and even more than that, you're arguing that they should know which language it came from and that it is a looping statement rather than a function, keyword, or other language construct.

Answer (score 1):

The list of possible answers is incomplete. It does not include [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (ES1) and [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (ES6) statements.

Secondly, I believe `foreach` does not refer to the [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ***method***. All options refer to looping constructs from various languages... `for-next` from VB/VBScript/VB.Net, `repeat-until` from Pascal and `foreach` from PHP. So if they meant which loops exist in JavaScript *literally* then:

1. The answer you chose is wrong.
2. Option #2 is the one that is <del>correct</del> not wrong. However it is missing `for...in` and `for...of`.

Finally, the explanation given to you is incorrect:

> Modern browsers implement ECMAScript4, and these do not support any
>   other loops.

Both of the above statements are wrong because (i) there is no such thing as ECMAScript4 (ii) `for...in` loop was always there. There is no further need to dissect the rest of explanation.

Comment: I cannot really choose an answer absent in the list. Which answer would you choose?

Comment: The second one does not contain any _incorrect_ option so second.